# HVAC leaking cold air at unit: seal with tape?

Tags: hvac, leak

I was in my crawlspace today and noticed that there was cold air leaking from a grouping of three round openings in my unit (pictured in the middle of the photo below). The outer two holes had rubber gaskets that I was able to adjust in order to stem the flow of air but the large black pipe in the middle had no gasket. While our home is cooling well at the moment, I am wondering if this is a problem I should have an HVAC repair person come look at, or if I can/should just seal these with HVAC tape myself.

[image: photo of leaking pipe entries]

Any advice here would be much appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of [duct seal](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905181647/http://www.idealind.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=duct-seal), will plug that hole right up.

[image: duct seal]
<sub>(source: [idealind.com](http://www.idealind.com/media/img/product/medium/31-601.jpg))</sub>

Grab a bit off the brick, and roll it into a snake (like you used to do with play-doh). Wrap it around the pipe, while pushing it into the hole.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Just wanted to be sure that there weren't internal problems causing this leak that I should have a pro look at.

Comment: @PhilipAllen Not likely. Those pipes are connected to the evaporator coil, which is in a pressurized chamber. If it's not sealed around the pipe, air is going to come out.